# Ruby return with double quotes

Tags: ruby, rspec

Hi I have a string passed back from rspec.

It should show 
`"alias/public_html/ab1/ab2/"`

but I am getting `"\"alias/public_html/ab1/ab2/\""`

I am getting the rspec error below:

```
 WebServer::HttpdConf#alias_path returns the aliased path                   
 Failure/Error: expect(httpd_file.alias_path('/ab/')).to eq 'alias/public_html/ab1/ab2/'

   expected: "alias/public_html/ab1/ab2/"
        got: "\"alias/public_html/ab1/ab2/\""

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/lib/config/httpd_conf_spec.rb:90:in `(root)'
```

And here is my actual program file

```
def alias_path(path)
  @hash_httpd['Alias'][path]
end
```

Please help

**EDIT**

Sorry, I am new to RUby, here is the httpd_file

```
def initialize(httpd_file_content)
  @hash_httpd = Hash.new
  httpd_file_content.each_line do | line |
    @commands = line.split
    if @commands.length == 2
      @hash_httpd[@commands[0]] = @commands[1]
    else

      if !@hash_httpd.has_key?(@commands[0])
        al = Hash.new
        @hash_httpd[@commands[0]] = al
      else
        al = @hash_httpd[@commands[0]]
      end

      al[@commands[1]] = @commands[2]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your string contains the quotes. We can't tell anything about the cause of this, nor the fix, unless you show what `@hash_httpd` looks like (or at least `@hash_httpd['Alias']`).

Comment: Your edit still does not show the value. I can only assume that in `httpd_file_content` there is a line like `Alias "alias/public/html/ab1/ab2/"`; your code does not strip the quotes, and they are preserved as is. If your file said something like `Alias alias/public/html/ab1/ab2/` instead, you would not have this problem. Given that you are using `split` indiscriminately, the quotes are misleading, and completely useless (they will not, for example, protect the value from being split on a space, like in shell).

Comment: Hi Amadan, I found where the string came from and yes they are as you said, which contains quotes, I tried to use gsub, but it doesn't seem to take it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that your `alias_path` output will be `"alias/public_html/ab1/ab2/"`, then you can just modify your `alias_path` method definition by removing the quotes (if any) from the returned path:

```
def alias_path(path)
  @hash_httpd['Alias'][path].gsub('"', '')
end
```